# System of linear equations over field

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

> Solve the system of linear equations
>   $$
> \begin{split}
> 2&x\ &+\ 17&y\ &= 1\\
> 7&x\ &+\   &y\ &= 2
> \end{split}
> $$
>   over $\mathbb{Z}_{23}$.

Can someone explain to me how to do this?

Comment: How would you solve it over the rationals?  There's really not a lot of difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use row reduction with the augmented matrix:

\begin{align}%
&\begin{bmatrix}\mkern-8mu\begin{array}{[rr|r}
2&17&1\cr 7&1&2
\end{array}\mkern-8mu\end{bmatrix}\xrightarrow{R_1\leftarrow12R_1}
%
\begin{bmatrix}\mkern-8mu\begin{array}{[rr|r}
1&-3&12\cr 7&1&2
\end{array}\mkern-8mu\end{bmatrix}\xrightarrow{R_2\leftarrow 7R_1-R_2}
%
\begin{bmatrix}\mkern-8mu\begin{array}{[rr|r}
1&-3&12\cr 0&1&13
\end{array}\mkern-8mu\end{bmatrix} \\[1ex]&\xrightarrow{R_1\leftarrow R_1+3R_2}
%
\begin{bmatrix}\mkern-8mu\begin{array}{[rr|r}
1&0&\color{red}5\cr 0&1&\color{red}{13}
\end{array}\mkern-8mu\end{bmatrix} 
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

You do it exactly the same like in the Rational numbers, just obey the arithmetic in $\Bbb Z/23\Bbb Z$.

For example, $\frac12\equiv12 \pmod{23}$ because $2\cdot 12=24\equiv1\pmod{23}.$

Comment: Okey, but in Rational numbers the solution is: x=11/39 and y=1/39 and what I should do with that?

Comment: Compute the multiplicative inverse of 39=16 in $\Bbb Z/23\Bbb Z$. It exists because $\gcd(23,39)=1$. I already showed you 1/2, take it to the 4th and you have 1/39=1/16.

Answer (score -1):

From the second equation we obtain:
$$6(7x+y)=12$$ or $$42x+6y=12,$$ which gives $$44x=13$$ or
$$-2x\equiv 13$$ or
$$x\equiv11\cdot13$$ or
$$x\equiv5.$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: How did you get first equation?

Comment: @Sa1m0n I added something. See now.